# Wrong results with "allow_soft_placement=True"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I am working on GPU computation of deep learning algorithms with tensorflow and some times experiencing strange results.\
For Example when I am using a pre-trained network which works well on CPU (though slow) and also gpu with the following config:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})
```

It works fine but not fast as I expected. The problems is that when I use the following configuration

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
```

it becomes fast but with wrong results!!

I will appreciate for your comments if you experienced such problems.

Here are some loges of using devices: I searched to see where it used cpu, I found the following logs:

```
-04-19 12:05:56.359434: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] group_deps: (NoOp)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:56.359452: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] keras_learning_phase/input: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
mbox_conf_final/Exp: (Exp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

(2)

```
2018-04-19 12:05:56.351642: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] Assign_42: (Assign)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
keras_learning_phase: (PlaceholderWithDefault): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV2: (NonMaxSuppressionV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
pool6_mbox_priorbox/Variable: (VariableV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

(3)

```
    2018-04-19 12:05:56.348320: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] keras_learning_phase: (PlaceholderWithDefault)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:56.348382: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV2: (NonMaxSuppressionV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:56.348446: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] pool6_mbox_priorbox/Variable: (VariableV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

(4)

```
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754020: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] non_max_suppression/iou_threshold: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] Placeholder_68: (Placeholder)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754056: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] Placeholder_67: (Placeholder)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754075: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] Placeholder_66: (Placeholder)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

(5)

```
    2018-04-19 12:05:44.754001: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV2/max_output_size: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754020: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] non_max_suppression/iou_threshold: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] Placeholder_68: (Placeholder)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754056: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] Placeholder_67: (Placeholder)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.754075: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] Placeholder_66: (Placeholder)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

(6)

```
    group_deps: (NoOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV2/max_output_size: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
non_max_suppression/iou_threshold: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.753194: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] conv8_2_mbox_priorbox/Tile/multiples: (Pack)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Placeholder_68: (Placeholder): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-04-19 12:05:44.753212: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:884] conv8_2_mbox_priorbox/Tile: (Tile)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Placeholder_67: (Placeholder): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Placeholder_66: (Placeholder): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```